# Which actual tools for mock testing of spring mvc application?

Tags: spring, testing, mocking

I want to practice mock testing. 
I need to test my MVC Spring application. What do you advice me to use?
I am beginning mock testing.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to start reading this information :

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html

Then if doubts arise post a question with the specific doubt that you have.

Thanks